# harmony of tenses, sentence construction , like/liked

Tags: tense, backshifting, tense-agreement

> I had no idea you **liked** movies of this sort.
>
> I had no idea you **like** movies of this sort.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?
Would the first one be more grammatically accurate than the latter, since its tenses are in harmony?

Comment: Why you didn't say "this sort of movies"? I am curious about it

Comment: I misread the question so I deleted my answer.

Comment: @Cardinal: this sort of, of this sort: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=movies+of+this+sort%2Cthis+sort+of+movie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmovies%20of%20this%20sort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20sort%20of%20movie%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Cardinal "this sort of" takes the singular: "this sort of movie" rather than "this sort of movies"

Comment: The first sounds more normal to me (can't explain why, problem of being a native speaker!)

Comment: @CharlieHarding got it, what about, "these sorts of things"

Comment: @TRomano It sounds interesting https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=movies+of+this+sort%2Cthis+sort+of+movie%2Cthese+sorts+of+things&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmovies%20of%20this%20sort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthis%20sort%20of%20movie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthese%20sorts%20of%20things%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Cardinal I believe that's the plural because __sorts__ is also in the plural: "this sort of thing" means one group, whereas "these sorts of things" means multiple groups, which are closely related. In reality both can be used interchangeably, but generally only the former is used when referring to a single initial thing.

Answer (score 2):

> > I had no idea you liked movies of this sort.
> >
> > I had no idea you like movies of this sort.

The first sentence is wrong, the second is OK.

In the first sentence "liked" is in the past tense, but "this" is in the present tense. So if you were discussing a movie you saw yesterday then the sentence should be:

> > I had no idea you liked movies of that sort.

The second sentence is about a movie, or kind of movie, under present discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Both the sentences are grammatically correct.

The first sentence means that someone liked some sort of movies earlier whereas the second sentence means that someone likes some sort of movies at present.